# Is concurrent stream limitation of Agora RTC SDK depend on video quality or only audio?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

In Agora FAQ I read one channel support 17 stream concurrently. Is this the limitation in case of only audio or low quality video streams are in the channel?

As I see in Agora sdk 4.x streams are replaced by tracks. Does it change something on limitation?

Thanks in advance,
László

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift from streams to tracks in the Agora Web SDK 4.x is to give developers greater control over the individual tracks (*audio, video*) instead of the high-level `stream` object (*which contains the tracks*). This does not have any effect on the number of users within the channel.

To scale beyond the 17 user limitations, there are a few different approaches. The recommended way for web would be to use multiple client objects to subscribe to multiple channels. To ensure there is no duplication of video streams, limit each user to only broadcast into a single channel. Make sure when you initialize each client, you add the event listeners before joining the channel.

Something to note when you have more than 17 streams/videos playing at one time it can be very CPU/GPU intensive, so you might want to use [Dual Stream mode](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#enabledualstream) to have a high quality and lower quality stream.